# Changing the Microsoft Word paste option for Excel tables?

Tags: microsoft-word, default-settings, paste

Is there a way to adjust default Microsoft Word paste option such that it paste table Excel as linked object in HTML Format? In the other words, I want the past/Paste special/past link/HTML Format be the default paste.

Comment: Do you mean you want the Paste Special --> Microsoft Worksheet Object to be the default paste?

Comment: I want the past/past link/HTML format be the default paste.